# Django: Loop through objects and their fields on template

Tags: python, django

I want to do something like this on **template**:

```
{% for account in integrations %}
   <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>#</td>
          <td>
            <p>{{ account.label }}</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
 {% endfor %}
```

**My views.py file:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import NewIntegrationForm
from modules import auth
from models import Worker

# Create your views here.

@login_required
def integrations(request):
    user = request.user
    all_integrations = Worker.objects.filter(user=user)
    if all_integrations != 0:
        return  render(request,
                   'integrations/index.html',
                   {'section': 'integrations', 'integrations': zip(all_integrations)})
```

**My models.py file:**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import uuid

# Create your models here.

class Worker(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        )
    a_key = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    a_secret = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

My web page return the result but it's empty. i.e. one row but the account.label is empty. Also if I don't zip, it shows 10 empty rows whereas there's only one object.

Comment: why are you using `zip` on the queryset ?

Comment: @PRMoureu If I don't it shows 10 empty rows on the page. It should be just one.

Comment: you mean it works without the zip() but you want to use it? why?

Comment: @zero No, I mean it shows 10 empty results when I don't use zip(). It should show only one.

Comment: maybe try with `all_integrations = get_object_or_404(Worker, user=user)`, without zip..

Comment: @PRMoureu "NameError at /integrations/
global name 'get_object_or_404' is not defined"

Comment: `from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404` sorry..

Comment: i commented the same time you answered it, sorry... but have you checked if your table doesn't have more data than you think though the admin interface? you can have few rows linked to the user without label @Raven

Comment: @PRMoureu TypeError at /integrations/
zip argument #1 must support iteration

Comment: @Raven you should remove the `zip` in this time.

Comment: @RajaSimon Yes, tried with zip removed too, no error but empty results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your views should be:

```
return render(request, 'integrations/index.html',
             {'section': 'integrations',
              'integrations': Worker.objects.filter(user=user)})
```

Your template should be:

```
{% if integrations %}
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Label</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for account in integrations %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
          <td>
            <p>{{ account.label }}</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
 {% else %}
    <strong> No records returned </strong>
 {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks! worked like a charm. Could you also explain why it worked please?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues.

Firstly, you are using `zip`. That makes no sense there and you should drop it.

Secondly, in the template you are accessing `account.link`. Your Integration model doesn't have a `link` field, so that will always be blank. You need to use an actual field or method on that model.

Comment: account.link I just added before posting the question, removed. And as I said removing zip shows empty rows, weird.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `zip`

```
{% for account in integrations %}
  <p>{{ account.0.label }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Without `zip`

```
{% for account in integrations %}
  <p>{{ account.label }}</p>
  {% for manyy in account.many_to_many_field.objects.all %}
    {{ manyy.somefield }}
  {% endfor %}  
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's because when you use `zip` python converting the list to sets. You can't access the set with positonal indicator. like `accounts.0`

Comment: You don't have to use zip at all... When you return django template will take care all. So when you iter in template you are getting the actual object in this way and you can do all the parameter access.

Comment: But the template is hardcoded with the first object, I don't see how it may work.

Comment: I told you already zip is unusual in this place... If integration contains list of worker querysets then just the iteration is enough to get all the field. If the fields in many to many then you can do next iteration in there as well. See my updated answer. But you don't have the many to many do you ?

Comment: It's one to many with foreignkey to user model but you've hardcoded the url to display the first object(account.0.label), how will it work with more than one in a loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154295/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-raven).

Answer (score 0):

First thing i would do is double check in admin panel if you don't have Workers registers with this user_id with empty labels, and just think it only have one record

If your query will only return a single worker, worker table will only map to one user, (unless they can be worker in different projects)

you should change

```
all_integrations = Worker.objects.filter(user=user)
```

to

```
all_integrations = Worker.objects.get(user=user)
```

try simple printing integrations without looping to see what is returned too, with the zip and without to check the different behavior, i would recommend not using zip

Comment: I already checked before posting this question. Using .get will only return one object but I need multiple objects to be returned, it has ManyToOne relation.

Comment: and what does the integrations print without looping though it?